# Disable (most) events on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of buttons with different events.

When the app is in 'super' mode I need to disable all of these events, but keep 2-3 of them active.

What would the best approach to do something like this? Do I need to unbind every handler or can I super some event that prevents default behavior?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of a way to simply disable and later re-enable (almost) all events on the page in an automatic way like you seem to be asking.

But two pretty easy techniques to achieve that end result are:

1. Unbind and then rebind later. A bit of a hassle if there are lots of bindings, and it sounds messy, but if you put all your binding code in a function, and all the unbinding code in another, turning them on and off is just a matter of calling those functions and you don't have duplicated code. You probably should cache the result of your initial jQuery selector in a variable so that you can unbind and rebind only the elements that originally matched the selector even if they've been updated such that they no longer match (e.g., if initially selecting by class and the class might later be removed).
2. Set an `eventsDisabled` flag, and have all your event handlers check that flag before doing anything.

Something simple like this works:

```
 var eventsDisabled = false;

 $("some selector").on("some event", function() {
     if (eventsDisabled) return;
     // actual event handling code here
 }

 // in some other part of your code:
 eventsDisabled = true; // turn off all events
```

Obviously the disadvantage to this is you have to add an extra line to the beginning of all your event handlers, except for the few that you want to remain active all the time, but it's just three words and some parentheses...

Answer (score 1):

try....

```
$(":button").unbind("click mouseover mouseout");
```

above code will unbind the specified events on all buttons, calling `unbind` without args will unbind all the events on all buttons on the page

Comment: and then rebind all of the handlers? That's what I'm trying to avoid if possible. I know I can unbind the events...

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Store Old Events */
var ClickEvents = $("#MyButton").data("events")["click"];
var OldEvents = new Array();
/* we have to do this because ClickEvents is a reference to the click events obj and gets modified on the unbind call below */
for( i in ClickEvents )
{
    OldEvents.push(ClickEvents[i]);
}
$("#MyButton").unbind("click");

/* Set Binds For "Super" */
$("#MyButton").click(function(){ alert("new bind");});
/* Reset old events when not "Super" */
$("#MyButtno").unbind("click");
for(i in OldEvents)
{
    $("#MyButton").click( OldEvents[i] );
}
```

Change "click" to whatever event you're wanting to manipulate

Might be easier just to make separate buttons for "super" mode, and hide the old buttons when in super, then bring them back when not in super.

Also if you want to just disable (unbind) some events and keep some, separate them to different namespaces

Example:

```
$("#MyButton").bind("click.SuperBinds",function()
{
    alert("a super bind");
});

$("#MyButton").bind("click.RegularBinds",function()
{
     alert("a regular bind");
});

/*disable regular binds, and keep SuperBinds click events*/
$("#MyButton").unbind("click.RegularBinds");
```